# Deploying Spring-boot web project in TomEE 7.1.0

Tags: spring-boot, apache-tomee, spring-web, tomee-7

I have created a simple spring boot web based project from STS, here is my pom file.

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.spring</groupId>
<artifactId>SQLServer-1</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1.1</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>SQLServer-1</name>
<description>SQLServer</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I have packed as a war file and tr deploying in TomEE, iam getting the error.

```
20-Sep-2018 18:18:03.800 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal Unable to deploy collapsed ear in war StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SQLServer-1-0.0.1.1]
 org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Creating application failed: D:\Softwares\Tomee Plus\apache-tomee-plus-7.1.0\webapps\SQLServer-1-0.0.1.1: javax.validation.spi.ConfigurationState.getValueExtractors()Ljava/util/Set;
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:1096)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:757)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1303)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1125)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:985)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:507)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1650)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1525)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.upload(HTMLManagerServlet.java:285)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:206)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:348)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBSecurityListener$RequestCapturer.invoke(OpenEJBSecurityListener.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.validation.spi.ConfigurationState.getValueExtractors()Ljava/util/Set;
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl.<init>(ValidatorFactoryImpl.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.buildValidatorFactory(HibernateValidator.java:38)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr.ConfigurationImpl.__privileged_doBuildValidatorFactory(ConfigurationImpl.java:332)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr.ConfigurationImpl.doBuildValidatorFactory(ConfigurationImpl.java)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr.ConfigurationImpl.buildValidatorFactory(ConfigurationImpl.java:324)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ValidatorBuilder$OpenEjbConfig.buildValidatorFactory(ValidatorBuilder.java:401)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ValidatorBuilder.buildFactory(ValidatorBuilder.java:111)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ValidatorBuilder.buildFactory(ValidatorBuilder.java:67)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.LazyValidatorFactory.ensureDelegate(LazyValidatorFactory.java:54)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.LazyValidatorFactory.getFactory(LazyValidatorFactory.java:65)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:975)
    ... 57 more
```

Not sure what is going wrong....

Comment: you should run the maven goal `spring-boot:run` to start a embedded application server that serves your spring boot application

Comment: Where can i specify that?

Comment: That's not what the reporter is asking, `mvn spring-boot:run` has nothing to do with deploying an app in TomEE.

Comment: @JagadheeswaranMohan you have incompatible Hibernate validators API on the classpath. TomEE ships with an older release that takes precedence. I don't know off the top of my head how to tell TomEE to stop doing that but their documentation should help you.

Comment: @StephaneNicoll thanks for the path provided. Went through [this] http://tomee.apache.org/tomee-and-hibernate.html documentation, is there anything better which explains the fix.

Comment: Can you provide a MWE via github? Others can then better help by debugging and checking the project setup.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue deploying a Spring Boot application as a war into a TomEE 7.1.0. container, and we resolved it with an entry in the META-INF/context.xml for the application war.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context path="/app/service">
  <Loader delegate="true"/>
</Context>
```

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/loader.html

> attribute = delegate
>
> Set to true if you want the class loader to follow the standard Java2 delegation model, and attempt to load classes from parent class loaders before looking inside the web application. Set to false (the default) to have the class loader look inside the web application first, before asking parent class loaders to find requested classes or resources.

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html

> Therefore, from the perspective of a web application, class or resource loading looks in the following repositories, in this order:
>
> 1. Bootstrap classes of your JVM
> 2. /WEB-INF/classes of your web application
> 3. /WEB-INF/lib/*.jar of your web application
> 4. System class loader classes
> 5. Common class loader classes
>
> If the web application class loader is configured with `<Loader delegate="true"/>` then the order becomes:
>
> 1. Bootstrap classes of your JVM
> 2. System class loader classes
> 3. Common class loader classes
> 4. /WEB-INF/classes of your web application
> 5. /WEB-INF/lib/*.jar of your web application

Comment: Thanks for the solution, will try the approach and will accept it.